# Homebrew not linking python correctly?

Tags: python, macos, homebrew

I installed both python 2.7.13 and python 3.6.2 with homebrew and updated my ~/.bash_profile as such:

```
# Homebrew
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

Python3 was linked fine. However, "which python" would still give me

```
/usr/bin/python
```

while "which python2" produces

```
/usr/local/bin/python2
```

It looks like homebrew installed python 2 as "python2" and never linked "python" to the new installation. This is causing me a lot of trouble down the road when installing virtualenvwrapper etc.

By the way, I also did
 `brew link python`.

Anybody know why this is and how to fix it?

Much appreciated!!

Comment: By the way, "pip" doesn't work on my terminal while "pip2" does. Not sure why, but it must be part of this problem.

Comment: Seems like that is the correct behaviour. Changing the default would certainly break any system utils that use Python. What problems is this causing you, exactly?

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for the response. When I tried to add "source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh" into my .bash_profile as instructed in an online guide, it gives me some errors basically saying the python at /usr/bin, which is the system default python, doesn't have virtualenvwrapper installed. This suggests somehow it's still looking at the system python, not the brew version.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They change that behavior [here](https://brew.sh/2017/07/31/homebrew-1.3.0/)

> Today I’d like to announce Homebrew 1.3.0. The most significant change
>   since 1.2.0 is that brew install python no longer installs a python
>   binary without manual PATH additions and instead installs a python2
>   binary. This avoids overriding the system python binary by default
>   when installing Python as a dependency. It also paves the way to
>   eventually have python be Python 3.x.

You will have to symlink python to the version of python installed by homebrew that you want.

You can do:

```
$ln -s /usr/local/bin/python2 /usr/local/bin/python
```

To symlink `python` to the homebrew Python2.x installation or do:

```
$ln -s /usr/local/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/python
```

to link it to the Python 3.x hombrew installation.

Comment: gsi-frank, thank you, I think that explains it. But how do I "symlink" python to the new version?

Comment: @Ning I edited my answer, test if that work for you.

Answer (score 0):

gsi-frank's solution solves the problem quite well but after using his solution, you might encounter problems with your pip3. Your pip3 might be linked to the old instance and therefore unusable for your new python instance.

Type `which pip3` to see where your pip3's path. 
**If your path is linked to your new instance, then ignore the rest of this answer.**

Type `echo $PATH` to see your current path. If it contains your old python instance's path then you will need to remove it from your `.bash_profile`

To solve this: check your `.bash_profile` and see if there is a path to your old python instance. 
If the old path is in there, you can delete it.

I had this problem and here's a link to the question if needed:
[How to change pip3 path after installing python with homebrew?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59241087/how-to-change-pip3-path-after-installing-python-with-homebrew?noredirect=1&lq=1)

To find your `.bash_profile`:

- Go to your Finder
- Right click and click `Go to a folder...` and type `~`
- Press `CMD` + `shift` + `.` to see hidden files
- Right click your `.bash_profile` and open in a text editor