# How to change pip3 path after installing python with homebrew?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, pip, homebrew

I previously installed Python 3 through the official distribution but recently decided to use Homebrew. I followed this to change my Python 3 path:
[Homebrew not linking python correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45952921/homebrew-not-linking-python-correctly)

This is how my python 3 path looks (which is what I want):

```
$which python
/usr/local/bin/python
$python --version
Python 3.7.5
```

However, now pip is using the official distribution but I want to change it to the Homebrew version

```
$which pip
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/pip

$pip --version
pip 19.3.1 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)
```

How do I change my pip path to the Homebrew version and remove the official distribution safely?

Comment: What does `echo $PATH` give you? Does it include `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework..`?

Comment: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

Comment: Actually I never recommend using homebrew or official package to install python for development machine, prefer to **pyenv**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework` from your `PATH`. That was added when you installed Python from the official distribution).  Or, at least not put it at the beginning, so that Homebrew's Python (the one in `/usr/local/bin`) will be the one used by your system.

In your `~/.bash_profile`, try this:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
```

then restart your Terminal or `source ~/.bash_profile`. Homebrew's `pip` should be in `/usr/local/bin`, installed along with Homebrew's Python.

That should also have been the fix for the system not using Homebrew's Python.

Comment: Removing it from my bash profile worked and leaving it blank produced the same result as your solution.  Is there any downside to leaving it blank?

Comment: Hmm, there's probably already a default value for `PATH` set by the system and by Homebrew. You can try `echo`-ing `$PATH` before the `export` line in bash.profile. If the default already has the same value as what I suggested, then it's better to just remove the `export` line or set it to `export PATH=$PATH`.

Comment: You're correct. The default path is the same as the path you provided. I changed my bash profile to ```export PATH=$PATH```  Thanks!